# Twitter Bootstrap 2 - Full width row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I asked a question yesterday with a similar issue however it would appear that I needed to do more leg-work. So thats what I did!

I have my basic 3 column layout (all be it, not exactly how I wanted it. The left and right columns are fluid and not fixed widths).

The issue is that the "row-fluid" DIV won't occupy the whole width of the screen or it's parent container which does stretch the width.

**EDIT
The left and right columns are all sitting perfectly with the fixed width however now the centre column won't fill up to the right hand column.**

HTML:

```
<div class="container-full">      
    <div class="navbar navbar-static-top">  
        <div class="navbar-inner blue-bg">
            <a href="#" class="brand"><img src="images/kab/logo-header.png" alt="KAB Logo Large"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="container-full">    
        <div class="row">

            <div class="span1 blue-bg" style="width: 150px;">
                <h4>Left Column</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="span10">
                <h4>Center Content</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="span1 right blue-bg" style="width: 150px;">
                <h4>Right Column</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="navbar-inner blue-bg" style="height: 77px;"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .container-full {
         margin: 0 auto;
         width: 100%;
     }

     .full {
          margin: 0 auto;
          width: 100%;
     }
```

EDIT: Code updated to reflect changes.

Comment: Probably good to mention which version of Bootstrap you are using.

Comment: I suppose u r using bootstrap 2 , If u want full width use row instead of row-fluid

Comment: @richard Thanks - its Twitter Bootstrap 2

Comment: @Genocide_Hoax - Yes its v2.3.2. That makes the row full width, but not the right column isn't all the way right. Any thoughts?

Comment: In Bootstrap 3 the grid system has changed and has no row-fluid. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid. You are using 2.3.2 , so Ill suggest you use row instead of row-fluid or manually browse to the section in bootstrap.css and remove the padding.

Comment: @Genocide_Hoax Thanks - I've made some tweaks, but somethings still not right. I've made a fiddle. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/270/)

In an ideal world I would like to have the columns as fixed widths (the centre being fluid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved! Sadly, I had to edit the bootstrap.css as it was always setting the margin-left regardless of what I did. I'm sure there is a way round this.

The solution below allows for a fixed - fluid - fixed 3 column layout

HTML:

```
   <div class="container-full"> 
     <div class="row">          
        <div class="span1" style="width: 150px;">
            <h4>Left</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="span10 filler">
            <h4>Center Content</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="span1" style="width: 150px;">
            <h4>Right</h4>
        </div>
     </div>     
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .filler {
        width: -moz-calc(100% - 300px); /* Firefox */
        width: -webkit-calc(100% - 300px); /* WebKit */
        width: -o-calc(100% - 300px); /* Opera */
        width: calc(100% - 300px); /* Standard */
    }
```

**The -300px value is equal to the sum of the fixed column widths, in this case 150px each.**

Now, on bootstrap.css goto line 282 `([class*="span"])` and change the `margin-left` from 20px to 0px.

Thats it! Worked for me. I must note that this only works with CSS3 due to the calc used in the CSS.

Comment: Worked for me without hacking the line. Just add style "margin-left: 0px !important;" on each div you need to hack

Answer (score 3):

With Bootstrap 2.x you don't need the class "container-full".
Bootstrap 2.x has the class "container-fluid" for fluid layouts (full width).

You can combine "container-fluid" and "row-fluid" for the expected outcome.

```
<body>
    <div class = "container-fluid">
      <div class = "row-fluid">    
         <div class="span1" style ="width: 150px;">
             <h4>Left</h4>
         </div>

         <div class="span10">
             <h4>Center Content</h4>
         </div>

         <div class="span1" style="width: 150px;">
             <h4>Right</h4>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

See more:  http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#layouts